# Loding selective column in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-redshift

I have a pipe deimeted txt data with 3 columns A,B & C in S3. Value in Column C also have pipe value so while loading my data is getting split into more than 3 columns.

Is there any way:

1. to load column with delimeter value
2. I don't really need column C, so is there a way I can load only column A & B

I have create a load_table with column A,B & C and using below copy command:

copy load_table
from S3_location
Authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just copy A and B  from the file -

```
COPY load_table(A, B) from ...
```

or A, B and the first part of C -

```
COPY load_table(A, B, C) from ...
```

Alternatively you can load the whole row (all columns) into a single column of a staging table by setting the delimiter to something not in the file (like ascii 001).  Then parsing out the columns using SQL and putting the result into the original target table.  In this way you can get the whole value of C loaded properly.